# Functions called by event listener running without the event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have these variables, referring to a button and a box

```
var showGreen = document.getElementById("showGreen");

var greenBox = document.getElementById("greenBox");
```

These functions are called by event listeners

```
function showBox(myElement){
  myElement.style.display = "block";
}

function hideBox(myElement){
  myElement.style.display = "none";
}

showGreen.addEventListener("click", showBox(greenBox));

hideGreen.addEventListener("click", hideBox(greenBox));
```

However, nothing happens when I click the button.
I did notice that getting rid of the hideBox function makes the box appear instantly, so I think the functions are running by themselves regardless of anything being clicked or not. Why?
The full code is here: http://jsbin.com/poxutopuhu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: You need to pass a function, not the result of the call

Comment: You may wanna bind the box: `...addEventListener("click",showBox.bind(this, greenBox))`

Answer (score 6):

It's because you shouldn't invoke the function inside event listener, it should look like this:

```
showGreen.addEventListener("click", showBox);
```

Otherwise (if you will invoke the function inside event listener), the function fill be executed when the interpreter will reach this line.

Or alternatively, if you want to pass a parameter, you can wrap the function in auxiliary function like this:

```
showGreen.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showBox(greenBox);
})
```

And here is the example:

```js
var showGreen = document.getElementById('showGreen');
function showBox(param) {
  console.log(param);
}
showGreen.addEventListener("click", function() {
  showBox('param');
})
```

```html
<button id="showGreen">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`showBox` evaluates as a function.

`showBox(greenBox)` *calls the function* and evaluates as its return value.

> ```
> showGreen.addEventListener("click", showBox(greenBox));
> ```

is essentially the same as:

```
var return_value = showBox(greenBox);
showGreen.addEventListener("click", return_value);
```

Since the function doesn't have a `return` statement, that return value is `undefined`.

You need to put a function as the second argument to `showGreen.addEventListener`.

Comment: I didn't realize I wasn't calling the function like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass variable into through addEventListener You should use scope of anonymous function like below

```
showGreen.addEventListener("click", function() { showBox(greenBox); } );
```

Also you have to be careful if you want to access "event" variable then you can't access above code then you can use below

```
showGreen.addEventListener("click", function(e) { showBox(greenBox,e); } );
```